# System.AccessViolationException Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opc, opc-da

When i compile there is no error but i have this exception (System.AccessViolationException )
even though this is a pretty simple code i am new to c# and can't find the problem
the url is correct but it does connect to my server and i'm using the proper packages but i doesnt scan the tags
the exception is in line :                 OpcDaBrowseElement[] elements = browser.GetElements(itemId);

The exception :
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Common;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Da;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Da.Browsing;
using System.Threading;

namespace OPCDA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();

            Uri url = UrlBuilder.Build("Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1");

            using (var server = new OpcDaServer(url))
            {
                server.Connect();
                var browser = new OpcDaBrowserAuto(server);
                BrowseChildren(browser);
            }

            
            void BrowseChildren(IOpcDaBrowser browser, string itemId = null, int indent = 0)
            {
                OpcDaBrowseElement[] elements = browser.GetElements(itemId);

                foreach (OpcDaBrowseElement element in elements)
                {
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', indent));
                    Console.WriteLine(element);

                    if (!element.HasChildren)
                        continue;

                    BrowseChildren(browser, element.ItemId, indent + 2);
                    

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the using directives and missing brackets please?  Then it will be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Could you also include the full details of the exception?

Comment: This is the library you are using, right? https://github.com/titanium-as/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client

Comment: TypeInitializationException's InnerException property is the property that contains the detail of the exception that was actualy thrown - this is the exception that you need to investigate

Comment: @AndrewMcClement the first exception has been handled, i have now another exception, i edited the post please check it, Thank you for ur help !

Comment: @phuzi i edited the post with more details please check it

Comment: @SebastianSiemens i edited the post with more details please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, all i did was change the build parameters to 32bit instead if 64 and it worked
Project\Build\CPU x86

Comment: consider accepting the answer even if its yours - for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

If a System.AccessViolationException occurs in the program, the process will be terminated, and the try catch cannot be caught.
There is a way to deal with it by adding the [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] attribute to the method that causes the exception, and try catch can catch the AccessViolationException exception without causing the process to terminate.